# PHP8 returning ZipArchive getStream from a function makes the containing zip archive to be closed

Tags: php, php-ziparchive, php-8, php-7.4

```php
private function getFilePointer($file)
{
    $pathInfo = pathinfo($file);
    
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (($res = $zip->open($file)) !== true) {
        throw new Exception("error");
    }
    
    $fileName = preg_replace('/\d+/', '', str_replace('.zip', '.csv', $pathInfo['basename']));
    
    if (!($stream = $zip->getStream($fileName))) {
        throw new Exception("error");
    }
    
    return $stream;
}
```

If the following function is used to get the zip stream and using it in
`$row = fgetcsv($stream)` it produces an error

```
PHP Error[2]: fgetcsv(): Zip stream error: Containing zip archive was closed
```

If using
`$zip->getStream($fileName)`
at the same function as you're trying to read with
`$row = fgetcsv($stream)`
then it doesn't throw an error.

It seems this behavior has changed from php7.4, but I couldn't find any documentation about it.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue, so the stream could be returned from a function and still be used?

Comment: I can confirm that in PHP 8.1 and 8.2 I receive the exception you are seeing, while 7.4 and 8.0 show no problems. My repro with steps is here: https://3v4l.org/oALrq. I can see some chatter about some stream changes [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/11044), but I can't tell if it is 100% related.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a garbage collection issue, can be solved using

```
static $zip = new ZipArchive();
```

you can also do:

```
return [ $stream, $zip ];
```

if you need it to be reentrant

Comment: ...which makes the code non-reentrant. I'm not convinced this is the best solution, but it could probably be working.